# Wikipedia Offline with Mac OS X 10.4 PPC?

Tags: macos, java, wikipedia

I've been searching around for this and have come up against a wall of dead links.

I have a PPC-based eMac that has OS X 10.4 and I would like to get an offline copy of Wikipedia (the reduced-content Simple English would be fine) on it because it won't be net-connected.

I've only found clients that were conceived too recently to support 10.4, and the official client, which requires Java 1.6, which requires OS X 10.5 (officially but also the buggy developer prerelease of 1.6 for 10.4 that was later nixed doesn't seem to have any working downloads anywhere anymore.)

Is there no way to accomplish this?  I'm not talking about a simple `wget` copy, but something where the search actually works, too.

Comment: Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download, you could build a local web server to do the indexing and searching. Not too hard with Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wikipedia offline requires an apache web server, PHP, and MySQL. All of those can run on MacOS 10.4. You just need to download the source code and compile yourself. You can also run [NetBSD for PowerPC](http://wiki.netbsd.org/ports/macppc/) if you want a modern operating system.